# How do I change the image based on the PFRelation?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a collection view with a  search bar that searches the db for the searched user. I can currently get the users that are searched for. The cell has a follow button, and when that is clicked the PFRelation is created and the follow button turns into a following button(it just changes the image of the button). My problem is whenever the user searches for another user, and he is already following the user, the follow button still appears, instead I want it to have a following button as the image. Below is my code.

```
var relation: PFRelation = (PFUser.currentUser()?.relationForKey("Friendship"))!

func followuser(sender: UIButton){
    let followbtn = sender
    let pointInTable: CGPoint = sender.convertPoint(sender.bounds.origin, toView: self.collectionview)
    switch(buttonState){
    case 0:
    if var indexPath :NSIndexPath = self.collectionview.indexPathForItemAtPoint(pointInTable){
        print(pointInTable)
        print(indexPath.item)

        relation.addObject(users[indexPath.item])
         print(relation)

        PFUser.currentUser()?.saveInBackground()
        followbtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Following"), forState: .Normal)
        }
    buttonState = 1;
    break;
    case 1:
       if var indexPaths :NSIndexPath = self.collectionview.indexPathForItemAtPoint(pointInTable){
        followbtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Follow"), forState: .Normal)
        relation.removeObject(users[indexPaths.item])
        PFUser.currentUser()?.saveInBackground()
       }
        buttonState = 0;
    default: break
    }

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return users.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionview.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("searchcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! searchcustomcell

    cell.follow.addTarget(self, action: "followuser:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    cell.follow.tag = indexPath.item


    if let value = users[indexPath.item]["username"] as? String{
        cell.searchname.text = value
    }

    if let value = users[indexPath.item]["ProPic"] as? PFFile{
        let finalImage = users[indexPath.item]["ProPic"] as? PFFile
        finalImage!.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock(){
            (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil{
                if let imageData = imageData{
                    cell.searchimage.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                    cell.searchimage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.searchimage.frame.size.width / 2;
                    cell.searchimage.clipsToBounds = true
                    }
            }
        }

    }



    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to query the "Friendship" relation, and store the results as an array **before** you start any searching (i.e. at `viewDidLoad`).

You may store it as an array of user ids, rather then an array of PFUser.
Let's call it `friends_ids`:

```
var friends_ids: [String] = []

let query = relation.query()
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
    (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if let objects = objects {
        friends_ids = objects.map({ (u) -> String in
            return u.objectId
        })
    }
}
```

Whenever you display a cell (`cellForItemAtIndexPath`), you should check whether the id of the `users[indexPath.item]` is contained in your `friends_ids` array.

```
if friends_ids.contains(users[indexPath.item].objectId){
    // hide/change 'follow' button
}
```

If it is in there, you can hide the "follow" button, of do whatever you like.

Comment: Please note, that this solution can be used, if you have a relatively small amount of users in the "friendship" relation.
If you you have more then 1000, than you have to use pagination due to the limitation of parse.
Also if you have many-thousands, then fetching all of them might not be the best solution.